# VS2013 IIS Express MVC5 Subdomains not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have done the following.

1. added the following to my host file

   127.0.0.1    dev.localhost.com
2. Changed the bindings for the site in IIS express config to

   ```
   <site name="MySite" id="19">
           <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Projects\MySite" />
           </application>
           <bindings>
               <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9888:localhost" />
             <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9888:dev.localhost.com" />
           </bindings>
       </site>
   ```
3. When i "Override applciation root URL" to http://dev.localhost.com and launch the error i get is "Unable to launche the IIS Express Web Server" 
   "The start URL specified is not valid http://dev.localhost.com" even though I have nothing in the start url box above.

and When i uncheck the override, when my site is in debug mode. going to http://dev.localhost.com results in page not found

**UPDATE**

I had to run IIS Express as admin for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Set IIS Express to run as admin, then changed the project url to http://dev.localhost.com:9888/ as well as overriding the root url to http://dev.localhost.com:9888/ now everything works as expected